# Coding style: curly bracket after 'if' statement

Tags: java

Which coding style is better and what are the types of people in the image programmers will know?

[image]

Which is better as a good programmer?

First writing curly braces after *if* statements or curly braces on a new line after the *if* statement?

```
  if(condition){
  }

  if(condition)
  {
  }
```

Comment: It's a matter of style - I personally prefer the first one.

Comment: There is no right or wrong answer here.  It is what you and your team find the most readable.

Comment: matter of taste. the second one produces more code lines... and makes code more unreadable...

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*).

Comment: Even if it was on-topic it would probably be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: None of the answers really address *"what are the types of people"*. Since it is from some presentation slide, it is really a human search engine question (who knows the (original) presentation and the required context to properly answer that question. The presenter probably had something very specific in mind—perhaps as some kind of a joke?)

Answer (score 6):

Although this is very much a matter of style, the "Java way" of doing it has always been to put the opening brace on the same line as the statement it is attached to. So

```
if(condition) {
}
```

is the suggested way of doing it. Who suggests this? Well, [Sun did](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#449) (and now Oracle maintains that page, too). And [Google does](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.1-braces).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that it's up to you to decide, which one suits you best. Also, from what I know, some languages are encouraging to use a specific style:

**Java** prefers *[camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)* and

```
if (true) {
}
```

**C#** *[PascalCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)* and

```
if (true)
{
}
```

However, it's important to keep the style consistent in the project. If you mix styles in a single file / project, that's bad practice.

Comment: As it is a matter of preferance, this isn't an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As other has written, there are certain standards that promote

```
if (whatever) {
}
```

as the "better" solution.

In that sense, "better" actually means:

- the majority of Java programmers is used to this style
- therefore, for the majority of programmers, it will be easier to read code that is following the common styles
- or vice versa: if you deviate from the common standards, everybody reading your source code will burn unnecessary brain cpu cycles to accustom to that deviating style

(and keep in mind: normally, source code is written "once"; but read maybe hundreds or thousands of time. thus "wasting brain cpu" is a **serious** issue)

But, on the other hand, the answer is: it depends.

My personal experience is: if you are following a consistent style, then the details of that style do not matter too much. You see, if your company has its own style conventions; and everybody is following those ... then you have to adapt. Period. And honestly: it is not that hard. I was asked to use all kinds of style conventions. And you simply adapt. It might take some time, but in the end, you will have no problems reading/writing code that maybe says

```
if (whatever)
{
```

So, when your team says: for our own good reasons, everybody has to use that second style, then that's it.

But if you are working on open source, or you are the person defining the style to use - then simply stay close to the "official" conventions from Oracle.

And final note: code formatting is a tooling question. You make sure that you specify your style convention so that your IDE can enforce it. Then you are even free to use your very personal style - just reformat source upon checkout; and turn back into "other peoples style" prior checkin to you source code repository.